# Why is clojure's start up time so slow?

Tags: performance, clojure

Something like this has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531616/why-is-the-clojure-hello-world-program-so-slow-compared-to-java-and-python); however, this doesn't really address the issue and just states that clojure is fast at run time but takes a while to start up. But *why* does it take so much longer than many other languages to compile? Is it because it contains so many functions and macros in its core library compared to commonly used OOP languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure application startup performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016440/clojure-application-startup-performance)

Comment: See http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/'Lean'+Runtime